# How to read/save HTTP Post response (HTML format) in angular 4

Tags: angular, angular4-httpclient

I am trying to read the HTTP Post response in Angular 4. But I cannot able to do. Because the response in HTML format. I searched many sites but I could not found any solution for that.

I can able read JSON format but HTML I can't able to do.

Please give me the solution for this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to add responseType text in the options object

```
const options = {responseType: 'text'}
this.http.post(url, body, options);
```

Comment: Thanks for idea. Its working good. But I can't add the Headers in this request. what to do for it?

Comment: You should be able to add them to the options object:
const options = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    // your headers
  }),
 responseType: 'text'
};

Perhaps calling it httpOptions would've made more sense